# Convert values based on parameter type using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reflection

I have a  array of objects and i want to convert these object in to its actual type based on the parameter type of a method using reflection .
The dictionary will change based on the json string.So I want to make the array of objects to proper type to pass the invoke method.

Here is my code .

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try

   string json =@"{""Id"":21}";
   Dictionary<string, object> paramList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Type jobType = (from t in asm.GetTypes()
                            where t.IsClass && t.FullName == "pathTest.Order"
                            select t).FirstOrDefault();
            MethodInfo infoMethod = jobType.GetMethod("GetOrder");
            object jobClassObject = asm.CreateInstance(jobType.FullName);
            ParameterInfo[] parameters = infoMethod.GetParameters();
            int count = parameters.Count();
            Object[] pArray = { };

            if (count > 0)
            {
                pArray = new object[count];

                foreach (var methodArg in parameters)
                {
                    var item = paramList.Where(m => m.Key == methodArg.Name).FirstOrDefault();


                    pArray[methodArg.Position] = Int32.Parse(item.Value.ToString());//hard coded

 //Here I want to cast the value based on parameter type . 
 //parameter type(item.Value.ToString())

                }


            }


            jobType.InvokeMember("GetOrder", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, jobClassObject, pArray);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual type of the parameter is stored in `methodArg.ParameterType`. You can use [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to change the type of the object you get from your json string:

```
Type paramType = methodArg.ParameterType;
pArray[methodArg.Position] = Convert.ChangeType(item.Value, paramType);
```